# How To pair and rearrange string values from a variable in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, string, variables

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJmLz.png)

Let me summarize the above code the first variable which is **Parttype** stores a list of part types from the input field, the second variable stores part labels and the third variable stores BIN numbers. As you can see my output from the commented code*(Line 187)*, I to take the first values and pair them together, take the second values and pair them together, and last values to pair them together too. How would I achieve this in PHP, just to summarize my question let me attach an image of what I want.

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0M8U.jpg)

Comment: you should use `.` (dot) in php for concatenation instead of `+`

Comment: Is expected solution supposed to be in the image format just as well?